# How can I mount a remote SSH folder on Mac?

Tags: ssh, mount

I do not like SFTP client applications, like Cyberduck. I want to access the SSH folder as a local disk driver, where you can read/write/copy/paste files.

I tried fuse4x+sshfs. It works but has a bug: the mounted driver disappears when Mac OS X wakes up, and I can not mount it again except by resetting Mac OS.

Is there a better choice?

Comment: I don't have any problem with sshfs and fuse4x, even after wakeup. What versions are you using? I use sshfs 2.4_0 and fuse4x 0.9.0_1 through macport.

Comment: Bug might be fixed by now.

Comment: I Still have the same issue. Transmit is terrible. Any kind of hiccup in network connection and suddenly and at random I get Input / Output errors or it unmounts itself with no warning or message.

Comment: You can use kill -9 <pid of sshfs> && diskutil unount force <device> instead of rebooting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Transmit - The ultimate Mac OS X FTP + SFTP + S3 app](http://panic.com/transmit/) can do this.

Another choice would be [ExpanDrive - SFTP/FTP/S3 Drive](http://www.expandrive.com/) but I think Transmit is the better option (I own both and am affiliated with neither).

There are demos of both programs available, so you can try both.

Note that Transmit is sold both through the Mac App Store and directly the developer (Panic). You would be better off buying it from Panic directly because of the impending sandboxing rules for the Mac App Store.

Comment: hmmm.. sounds cool!

Comment: I voted and bought Transmit but I am not pleased about the performance at all. I work with local linux servers and it seems to be too slow, also seems to do a lot of caching and it does not detect file being changed on the server even after many minutes. I will be more than interested in finding a solution for this problem.

Comment: I can't figure out how to mount my SFTP server as a drive on MacOS Monterey with Transmit and Expandrive cannot authenticate with my server for some reason. Any clues?